# Do addEventListener/attachEvent Suffer From Memory Leak Patterns?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks

I've read some articles regarding javascript memory leakage patterns (e.g. [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms976398.aspx), [IBM article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-memleak/)).

I understand attaching a handler (onclick for instance) property to an element creates a leak due to the handler closing over the element:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('foo');
elem.onclick = function () {
     // Creates leak
}
```

My question: Do the addEventListener/attachEvent interfaces cause the same problem? Don't their functions close over the element as well, and wouldn't this cause a leak for the same reason?

```
var elem = document.getElementById('foo');
elem.addEventListener('click', function () {
    // Doesn't this also close over elem?
}, false);
```

If the above doesn't cause a leak, why not? And if not, how is this code for attachEvent different which MSDN says causes a leak (I understand attachEvent is quickly becoming obsolete, but provided the example there)?

```
function AttachEvents(element)
{
    // This structure causes element to ref ClickEventHandler
    element.attachEvent("onclick", ClickEventHandler);

    function ClickEventHandler()
    {
        // This closure refs element
    }
}

function SetupLeak()
{
    // The leak happens all at once
    AttachEvents(document.getElementById("LeakedDiv"));
}
```